# how to load gridview in a div on click of horizontal menu?

Tags: jquery, html, tabs, containers

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/24x7master.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="admintabcontainer.aspx.cs" Inherits="_24x7Timesheet.admintabcontainer" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

    <%--<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>--%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <%--<script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
    <link href="styles/Standard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
    <script src="MainContentForm.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
--%>
    <div class="notebox" id="divx">  
    <p>  
        Hello <%= Request.Form["name"] %>,  
    </p>  

    <p>  
        This content was dynamicly created at:  
        <%= DateTime.Now.ToString("T") %>  
    </p>  

</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/alinkhover.js"></script>

    <%-- <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
             debugger;
             $("#Button1").click(function() {
                 alert("Hello world!");
             });

         });
        </script>--%>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="CSS/Stylesheet.css" />
  <%-- <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
 <style type="text/css">
        .ajax__tab_outer
        {
            margin-right: 05px !important;
        }
        .ajax__tab_body
        {
            border: none !important;
        }
        .ajax__tab_header
        {
            background: none !important;
        }

     .divPage
    {

        width:300px;

        height:200px;

    }

    </style>
    <%--<script type="text/javascript">--%>

<%--     </script>--%>
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">




   function check_uncheck(Val) {

            var ValChecked = Val.checked;
            var ValId = Val.id;
            var frm = document.forms[0];
            // Loop through all elements

            for (i = 0; i < frm.length; i++) {

                // Look for Header Template's Checkbox
                //As we have not other control other than checkbox we just check following statement
                if (this != null) {

                    if (ValId.indexOf('chkSelectAll') != -1) {
                        // Check if main checkbox is checked,
                        // then select or deselect datagrid checkboxes

                        if (ValChecked)

                            frm.elements[i].checked = true;
                        else
                            frm.elements[i].checked = false;
                    }
                    else if (ValId.indexOf('chkSelect') != -1) {
                        // Check if any of the checkboxes are not checked, and then uncheck top select all checkbox
                        if (frm.elements[i].checked == false)
                            frm.elements[1].checked = false;
                    }
                } // if
            } // for
        } // function

        function confirmMsg(frm) {
            // loop through all elements
            for (i = 0; i < frm.length; i++) {
                // Look for our checkboxes only
                if (frm.elements[i].name.indexOf("chkSelect") != -1) {
                    // If any are checked then confirm alert, otherwise nothing happens
                    if (frm.elements[i].checked)
                        return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete your selection(s)?')
                }
            }
        }



    </script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">



    <div class="sample">  
        Enter your name: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" />  
        <input type="button" id="btnLoadDynamic"   
               value="Load Dynamic Content (external ASPX)" />              

        <div id="dynamic" class="hidden">  
        </div>      
    </div>  


     <div>
          <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

     </div>
     <div id="divtop" align="left" > 


<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlproject" runat="server" 
            AppendDataBoundItems="true">
  <asp:ListItem Value="">Please select a Project</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>    
</div>
<div>
</div>
    <div align="left">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager> 
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" Width="900" ActiveTabIndex="1">

   <asp:TabPanel  runat="server" ID="TabPanel1">
   <HeaderTemplate>
  Projects
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ContentTemplate>

<asp:GridView ID="gvproject" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
           AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
                                            Font-Names="verdana" Font-Size="11px" 
           ShowFooter="True"    BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" 
           BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3"
                                            GridLines="None" Width="96%" OnPageIndexChanging="gvproject_PageIndexChanging"  
                                            OnSorting="gvproject_Sorting" >
                                             <HeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" />
                                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" />
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                                 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" runat="server" Text="" onclick="return check_uncheck (this );"
                                                AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelectAll_CheckedChanged"  />
                                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" Visible="true" onclick="return check_uncheck (this );"/>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProjectName">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink id="hl" Runat="Server" NavigateUrl='<%# "ProjectDetails.aspx?Id=" + Eval("Projectcode")%>' Text='<%# Eval("ProjectName","{0:d}")%>'></asp:HyperLink> 
</ItemTemplate>
                <ControlStyle ForeColor="Black" />
</asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Projectcode" DataField="Projectcode" />
         <asp:boundfield headertext="Priority"
            datafield="Priority" />

         <asp:boundfield headertext="EstimatedTime"
            datafield="estimatedtime" />

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Edit"
                                    ImageUrl="~/Images/edit-icon.png" ToolTip="Edit" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="60px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="delete">
                        <ItemTemplate> 
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtndelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Delete"
                                    ImageUrl="~/Images/delete-icon.png" ToolTip="Edit" />                     
                        </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="60px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
                                             <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
                                             <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                             <RowStyle BackColor="#D3EDFE" ForeColor="Black" />
                                             <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" />
</asp:GridView>

   </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:TabPanel>
   <asp:TabPanel runat="server"  ID="TabPanel2">
    <HeaderTemplate>
   Users
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ContentTemplate>
       <div class="chromemenu">
    <ul>
<li>
<asp:HyperLink ID="hl" runat="server">New</asp:HyperLink>
<a  href="admintabcontainer.aspx?&id=abc"  >
<span>New</span>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="Default.aspx">
<span>New Task</span>

</a>
</li>
</ul>

</div>

<div id="abc">

<%--    class="divPage"
--%>    <div id="LoadPage" >
hi
    </div>

    </div>
   </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:TabPanel>
   <asp:TabPanel runat="server"  ID="TabPanel3">
    <HeaderTemplate>
   Regions
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ContentTemplate>
     this is academic information panel

   </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:TabPanel>
    </asp:TabContainer>


</div>

<%--</div>--%>
 </asp:Content>


/* jquery for hovering */

$(document).ready(function() {
//    debugger;
//$('#<%=Button1.ClientID %>')

$("input[id$='Button1']").click(function() {
        alert("Hello world!");
    });

});
```

Comment: Post only relevant parts of your code and explain your problem a little bit more.